# Python priority queue class wrapper

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, priority-queue

I'm trying to incorporate the advice found in https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/heapq.html in order to make a priority queue implementation (see corresponding section) in a class `priorityQ`. Not going to reinvent the wheel so i use the the python's heapq implementation

```
class priorityQ():
    import heapq
    import itertools

    def __init__(self,mylist):

        self._entry_finder = {}               # mapping of tasks to entries
        self._counter = itertools.count()     # unique sequence count
        self.REMOVED = '<removed-task>'      # placeholder for a removed task

        if mylist:
            self.data = []
            for element in mylist:
                priority, count, task = element[0], next(self._counter), element[1]
                entry = [priority,count,task]
                self._entry_finder[task] = entry
                heapq.heappush(self.data,entry)
        else:
            self.data = []

    def add_task(self,task,priority):
        if task in self._entry_finder:
            self.remove_task(task)
        count = next(self._counter)
        entry = [priority,count,task]
        self._entry_finder[task] = entry
        heapq.heappush(self.data, entry)

    def remove_task(self,task):
        'Mark an existing task as REMOVED.  Raise KeyError if not found.'
        entry = self._entry_finder.pop(task)
        entry[-1] = self.REMOVED

    def pop_task(self):
        while self.data:
            priority, count, task = heapq.heappop(self.data)
            if task is not self.REMOVED:
                del self._entry_finder[task]
                return task
        raise KeyError('pop from an empty priority queue')
```

The code as it is seems to solve the implementation challenges listed in 8.5.2 in the link I gave. I just wonder if this is a clean implementation of such a candidate class. Is it better to just implement with the procedural style suggested in the manual and incorporate it in whatever project i'm working on or is it a better practice to make use of a class like the above (or a more refined version of that).

PS: I know it's slightly off-topic for this stack exchange site, but i wonder if there is a way around the side effect of having a bunch of deleted-entries residing in the queue after doing a set of priority updates in existing tasks. (Something different than copying/cleaning the entire queue every fixed period of time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1. Review

1. The code in the post does not work:

   ```
   >>> q = PriorityQueue(())
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "cr152757.py", line 8, in __init__
       self._counter = itertools.count()     # unique sequence count
   NameError: name 'itertools' is not defined
   ```

   The problem is that `itertools` was imported in class scope (not at top level) so you need `self.itertools` (or to move the imports to the top level).
2. The class has no docstring. How am I supposed to use this class?
3. The `__init__`, `add_task` and `pop_task` methods have no docstrings. What arguments do I pass? What do they return?
4. The objects in the queue are described as "tasks" but priority queues can be used for all sorts of different things — for example, the [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) uses a priority queue containing unexpanded search nodes. I would use a more generic name like "item" or "element", and change `add_task` to `add`, `remove_task` to `remove` and `pop_task` to `pop`.
5. The Python style guide ([PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)) recommends that

   > Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.

   So I would call the class `PriorityQueue`. You're not obliged to follow this guide, but it will make it easier for you to collaborate with other Python programmers if you do.
6. If a class has no superclasses, then you can omit the parentheses from the class declaration.
7. The constructor has a required argument `mylist`. It would be better if this argument was optional, and if omitted then the constructed queue is empty. This would match the behaviour of other class constructors like [`queue.PriorityQueue()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.PriorityQueue) and [`collections.deque()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) which construct empty queues if given no argument.
8. There is a test `if mylist:` but this is unnecessary because if `mylist` is an empty list, then both branches have the same behaviour (setting `self.data` to the empty list). So you might as well omit the test.
9. Once you omitted the test on `mylist`, it doesn't have to be a list any more – any iterable would do. So I would name this argument `iterable`.
10. It is perverse that the argument to `__init__` must be a list of pairs (priority, task) but when calling `add_task` you have to supply the arguments (task, priority). This seems likely to be the cause of errors.
11. The need for `_counter` is slightly tricky (it's necessary to break ties in case the items cannot be compared for order), so a comment would be a good idea.
12. `self.REMOVED` is always the same, so it could be a member of the class. Also, it is only needed for use internally by the class so PEP8 recommends using a name starting with an underscore.
13. Similarly, `self.data` ought to have a name starting with an underscore.
14. Instead of using `element[0]` and `element[1]` here:

    ```
    for element in mylist:
        priority, count, task = element[0], next(self._counter), element[1]
        entry = [priority,count,task]
    ```

    use tuple unpacking:

    ```
    for priority, item in iterable:
        entry = [priority, next(self._counter), item]
    ```

    (But see the next item.)
15. The code in `__init__` duplicates the code in `add_task`. So it would be simpler if the former called the latter:

    ```
    for priority, item in iterable:
        self.add(item, priority)
    ```
16. The docstring for `remove_task` is written from the implementer's point of view: it says, "Mark an existing item as REMOVED". But the user does not need to know how removal is implemented: that's an internal detail of the class which the documented API should hide.
17. In `pop_task` you unpack all the elements of the popped entry:

    ```
    priority, count, item = heapq.heappop(self._data)
    ```

    but `priority` and `count` are not used. It is conventional to use the variable name `_` for values that go unused.

#### 2. Revised code

```
import heapq
import itertools

class PriorityQueue:
    """Collection of items with priorities, such that items can be
    efficiently retrieved in order of their priority, and removed. The
    items must be hashable.

    """
    _REMOVED = object()         # placeholder for a removed entry

    def __init__(self, iterable=()):
        """Construct a priority queue from the iterable, whose elements are
        pairs (item, priority) where the items are hashable and the
        priorities are orderable.

        """
        self._entry_finder = {} # mapping of items to entries

        # Iterable generating unique sequence numbers that are used to
        # break ties in case the items are not orderable.
        self._counter = itertools.count()

        self._data = []
        for item, priority in iterable:
            self.add(item, priority)

    def add(self, item, priority):
        """Add item to the queue with the given priority. If item is already
        present in the queue then its priority is updated.

        """
        if item in self._entry_finder:
            self.remove(item)
        entry = [priority, next(self._counter), item]
        self._entry_finder[item] = entry
        heapq.heappush(self._data, entry)

    def remove(self, item):
        """Remove item from the queue. Raise KeyError if not found."""
        entry = self._entry_finder.pop(item)
        entry[-1] = self._REMOVED

    def pop(self):
        """Remove the item with the lowest priority from the queue and return
        it. Raise KeyError if the queue is empty.

        """
        while self._data:
            _, _, item = heapq.heappop(self._data)
            if item is not self._REMOVED:
                del self._entry_finder[item]
                return item
        raise KeyError('pop from an empty priority queue')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. One question: Is there a substantial reason for binding _REMOVED to an Object() instance instead of a string like in the first place? Does it in some way have to do with garbage collection?

Comment: @Sorrop: It's because I want to be sure that `_REMOVED` is different from all items that anyone might try to store in a queue. Imagine that someone tried to store the string `'<removed-task>'` in a queue, could this result in the queue thinking that the item had been removed? The Python language specification doesn't guarantee that duplicate strings will be different objects.